# Color emoji arrows in emacs

Tags: emacs28, fontsets, emojis

I have attempted to setup emacs 28.2 to display color emojis using the Noto Color Emoji font.  According to a "Font Manager" program (provided by `font-manager` Debian package), the following symbols are among the glyphs available within the Noto Color Emoji font: ↔, ↕, ↖, ↗, ↘, ↙, ↩, ↪.

I have attempted to use both

```
(set-fontset-font t 'symbol "Noto Color Emoji")
```

and

```
(set-fontset-font t 'emoji "Noto Color Emoji")
```

to configure the rendering of the symbols under consideration with the Noto Color Emoji font in Emacs buffers.

However, whenever I attempt to input them in an Emacs buffer, they end up rendered with my default font.  Yet, emoji symbols like ❇ ✨ do render as expected, in full color, and with Noto Color Emoji font.

I am not sure what is the root cause of the problem.  I have attempted to adopt some code suggested at the https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/62220/40231 to setup code tables, as well as to use `emojify` package as suggested at the https://ianyepan.github.io/posts/emacs-emojis/.  In both cases, I got the negative result.  When I used `emojify` package, I did get a correct rendering with its internal png-based insets; after setting the

```
(setq emojify-display-style 'unicode)
(setq emojify-emoji-styles '(unicode))
```

I got the same negative (i.e. rendering with default font for some symbols) result.

Could you please suggest, what may be the root cause of the issues that I am experiencing?  Could you please assist me with developing a fix?

**UPDATE**  I attempted a following experiment.  I have created the following file, then I ran emacs as `emacs -Q` and evaluated lines of that file:

```
;; ↔, ↕, ↖, ↗, ↘, ↙, ↩, ↪.

❇✨

(set-fontset-font t 'emoji "Noto Color Emoji")

(set-fontset-font t 'symbol "Noto Color Emoji")
```

An end result had been that only the ✨ got rendered with Noto Color Emoji font.  The rest were rendered with Deja Vu Sans Mono.

**UPDATE** I have noticed that the problem does not occur if the text is commented, and is displayed in a corresponding face.  That behaviour seems a bit weird to me, since I am not using anything more sophisticated in my face definitions than

```
;; ...
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :foreground "white" :background "black" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 160 :width normal :font "Inconsolata"))))
;; ...
 '(font-lock-comment-face ((t (:background "black" :foreground "white" :distant-foreground "snow" :slant oblique :weight normal :height 160 :font "Inconsolata"))))
;; ...
```

Comment: Does this happen for you with `emacs -Q`? Your recipe works fine for me.

Comment: @rpluim, No, I'm not running with the `-Q` switch.  Also, the Debian package designation is `emacs-gtk 1:28.2+1-10`.

Comment: I've just tried that with `emacs -Q` on a debian-testing machine, and it all works. Do you have any local fontconfig files (see PROBLEMS, which you can reach via `C-h C-p`)

Comment: @rpluim I'm looking at the help section suggested; thank you.  Would you also possibly check my UPDATE about the interaction of this issue with the comment face.  That latter part seems really weird, since in the commented text I am able to achieve the desired rendering, whereas in un-commented text I could not.  I assume, the fontconfig issues are related to the inability to render characters at all.  In this case, it seems, the issue is more along the lines of what font the _emacs_ chooses or fails to choose.

Comment: I can't explain that: the fontset settings should override your default face (and in `emacs -Q` there are no such face settings, so I don't understand why it's not working for you)

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a try and it partly worked for me. My preferred font, Input Mono Condensed, already has glyphs for two of those arrows. For the others it had to fall back to a font with a noticeably different size (almost unreadably small for some reason).

When I ran `(set-fontset-font t 'symbol "Noto Color Emoji")`, the fallback behavior changed and now those six arrows are displayed using the Noto Color Emoji font, while the first two are still displayed using Input Mono Condensed.

> `(set-fontset-font t 'emoji "Noto Color Emoji")`

There’s no reason to expect this to do anything much for your test, since the arrow characters you are interested in are in the `symbol` script, not the `emoji` script.

Comment: How does your _emacs_ behave when run with the `-Q` switch?